# Bind to a WPF DataGrid disappears after saving a file

Tags: wpf, binding, datagrid

I have a `WPF` DataGrid:

```
<DataGrid SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedXIndex,Mode=TwoWay}" DataContext="{Binding MyViewModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding XList}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
...
</DataGrid>
```

The `ItemSource` is bind to a list that sits in my ViewModel.

```
 private ObservableCollection<X> _xList= new ObservableCollection<X>();
    public ObservableCollection<X> XList
    {
        get
        {
            return _xList;
        }
        set
        {
            _xList= value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("XList");
        }
    }
```

Class X contain Name(string) and Value(int).

I have a button when pressed it saved on file the list items that are full of details (Name and Value).

Once it is saved the bind to the DataGrid does not work in ItemSource I have several items differently than in XList.

Here's saving function:

```
    public void SaveToFile(string path)
    {
        XList= FilterCommands();//Return the full value commands
        List<X> serlist = new List<X>();

        for (int i = 0; i < XList.Count; ++i)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(XList[i].Name))
            {
                serlist.Add(XList[i]);
            }
        }
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<X>));
        TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(path);
        serializer.Serialize(textWriter, serlist);
        textWriter.Close();
    }
```

I can not understand why this happens.

(It seems to me that the problem probably is opening a dialog save, but how to solve it?)

Comment: _"I have several items differently than in XList"_ - Please explain what *exactly* happens...

Comment: @benPearce It really was the problem, put it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the FilterCommands method is replaceing the contents of the ObservableCollection.

What exactly does that method do? Is it changing the collection?

Comment: You right, The filter command return IList and not ObservableCollection, And that was the problem